# How to get course image from Moodle API

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I am pulling a list of courses from my Moodle site via the API but there is no image url or image name in the response. Is there a way to get it?

Maybe the particular endpoint I am using is wrong but I can't find another one to list all courses (for non-logged in users, so all available courses)

```
https://example.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=12312312312123&wsfunction=core_course_get_courses&moodlewsrestformat=json
```

Example response:

```
{
"id": 1,
"shortname": "A course title",
"categoryid": 3,
"categorysortorder": 10001,
"fullname": "A full course name ",
"displayname": "Some course",
"idnumber": "",
"summary": "",
"summaryformat": 1,
"format": "topics",
"showgrades": 1,
"newsitems": 5,
"startdate": 1588716000,
"enddate": 0,
"numsections": 7,
"maxbytes": 0,
"showreports": 0,
"visible": 1,
"hiddensections": 0,
"groupmode": 0,
"groupmodeforce": 0,
"defaultgroupingid": 0,
"timecreated": 1588703577,
"timemodified": 1589199433,
"enablecompletion": 1,
"completionnotify": 0,
"lang": "",
"forcetheme": "",
"courseformatoptions": [
{
"name": "hiddensections",
"value": 0
},
{
"name": "coursedisplay",
"value": 0
}
]
},
```

Answer (score 2):

On your webservice url use this

`core_course_get_courses_by_field` function with specific course id or list of ids.

instead  `core_course_get_courses`

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way:

```
$course = get_course($courseid);
\core_course\external\course_summary_exporter::get_course_image($course);
```

The `course_summary_exporter` function expects a plain object describing the course (basically a row from the courses table as object) and returns the URL of the image or  `false` if no image is set.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking through the code in `/course/externallib.php`

It looks like the service `core_course_search_courses` returns a field called `overviewfiles` for each course - which contains `fileurl` which should be the link to the image.

I haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will take a look into that and post back in due course.

Comment: When I try that I get an error: invalid_parameter_exception. I think it might be expecting me to pass some data into this one but I don't want to pass anything in, I literally just want to get a list of all courses back for frontend users to see on a website. They don't have to be logged in.

Comment: in addition to the url you need to add {&token=yourtoken}